# Does mod_rewrite set `Alias` automatically or should it be explicitly specified when doing a `RewriteBase`?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

From: [RewriteBase <sup>Apache Docs</sup>](http://www.askapache.info//2.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase)

```
        #  /abc/def/.htaccess -- per-dir config file for directory /abc/def
        #  Remember: /abc/def is the physical path of /xyz, i.e., the server
        #            has a 'Alias /xyz /abc/def' directive e.g. #

        RewriteEngine On

        #  let the server know that we were reached via /xyz and not
        #  via the physical path prefix /abc/def
        RewriteBase   /xyz

        #  now the rewriting rules
        RewriteRule   ^oldstuff\.html$  newstuff.html
```

Does these lines:

```
        #  Remember: /abc/def is the physical path of /xyz, i.e., the server
        #            has a 'Alias /xyz /abc/def' directive e.g. #
```

mean that 
*mod_rewrite sets `Alias /xyz /abc/def'` automatically based on the .htaccess file or show this be specified explicitly in the conf file?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not set the [Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) automatically: you need to explicitly define it in your server config, not .htaccess